# How to get media information in Dolphin?

Tags: files, plasma, ubuntu-studio, dolphin, media

I can select media information entries to display in details view, but the listed columns are empty.

Width, height, duration, or any other information for pictures, sound-files or videos can't be displayed.

How can I get the correct media informations in dolphin?

**System information:**

```
Dolphin 21.12.3

Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-70-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700K
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
```

**Additional Informations:**

- File Search has been disabled in system settings, no index exists. (I've tried with it enabled and full index too ...)
- "kid3" is installed.
- It does not make any difference, wether its on a NTFS,
  ext4, FAT32, smb or any other file system.

Dolphin shows:
[image: Dolphin view]

A view to the information panel on the right side shows the correct data. So the information is available for dolphin.

---

Just to clarify the question, wether indexing has to be enabled, or not:

With indexing enabled (including content):
[image: Indexing enabled with content]

On my system, Dolphin does NOT show Width and Duration in its columns, but still in the preview. The display according to the first picture above has not been changed.

The pictures show also, that the path for the displayed movies and images are within the indexed path.

There must be some other settings or configurations, to get it working, but out-of-the-box it does not work on Ubundu Studio 22.04 LTS.

Comment: There is no other setting, it should work as I described in my answer. Since it didn't for you, I'd assume that your database-file and/or configuration files are corrupted, maybe due to a version conflict caused by a release upgrade. You could try to remove these files from your home directory and start over. Files in question are `~/.config/baloofilerc`, `~/.config/baloofileinformationrc`, `~/.local/share/baloo/index` and `~/.local/share/baloo/index-lock`. But I can't promise that it will be successful.

Answer (score 1):

One solution contains the following steps:

1. Add ***.pdf** to `/home/sd/.config/baloofilerc`

   [Basic Settings]
   Indexing-Enabled=true

   [General]
   dbVersion=2
   exclude filters=*~,*.part,*.pdf,...
2. Stop indexing and wait ... After some time (could be hours) a dialog opens, to remove the index -> Remove it!
3. Open a terminal and use `balooctl purge`. (Don't use sudo!)
4. Open the settings panel and activate indexing again. Make sure, only the paths are activated, where you realy want an index, before you apply it.

The reason to add ***.pdf** to the exclusion list: I observed, that everytime, the index was on a PDF file, it took a very long time to go further, up to 10 minutes, depending on its complexity. PDFs could be in media folders, containing descriptions for movies, movie books, artist descriptions, scores and even picture albums. After a full index, the media info for other file types was still not available, but after excluding PDFs from the index, doing the above steps, everything was fine.

The result:
[image]

It took again several hours, to rebuild the new index, but now I'm happy :)

Comment: Thumbs up for not giving up and at last findig a solution. Although I cannot reproduce your problem, but hey, you have a lot more data and huge number of files. Hope my hints have been useful on your way...

Comment: @mook765 Yes, thank you. **Your** hints gave me the conviction, that something has been wrong with indexing on **my** machine. So it seems in my eyes, that some PDFs are leading to a malfunction ... observable on long times, when the index build is on such a file. I thaught, it could corrupt the whole index at the end -> and that's the reason, why I've tried, to remove PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

You need file search enabled in the system settings and also index file content. Add the folder you want to be indexed with the `Add folder configuration...`-button to the list. The indexing is recursive, means also files in subfolders of the added folder will be indexed. Dolphin will be able to display the metadata in that columns only for files in indexed folders.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
The indexing is now running since yesterday: 44% and goes not further.

Comment: @dschoni For me indexing took less than a minute on a 800GB partition, it may depend on storage size and number of files though. Maybe you can narrow down indexing to only folders where you really need it.

Comment: There is a changing display of files, which are indexed at the moment, even PDFs, ZIPs, and more - every single file in the path. I've enabled only a part for indexing and I hope, this works for this path with ~10TB of data and half a million of files ...

Comment: Sometimes it takes half a minute for 1 PDF file, then sudenly, some files are going very fast ...

Comment: Well I let it run, up to tomorrow.

Comment: Indexing has been completed.
Dolphin does still not show the required information.

Comment: Please see https://community.kde.org/Baloo for limitations. BTW, I'm doing this on Ubuntustudio 22.04 without any hazzle.